# Losing results when iterating over 1 to many table

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-connector

My dilemma is that I am losing my ResultSet from the primary table when accessing a foreign key table.  I need to save the results from the first table query while I query another table.

Scenerio:
I am implementing a recipe database system.  Each recipe can have 1 to many ingredients.  To resolve the 1 to many relationship, I created a separate table for the ingredients.

I have a table of recipes:

```
  ID_Recipe: primary key, integer;   
  Recipe_Title: CHAR(128);
```

And a table of ingredients:

```
ID_Ingredient:  PRIMARY KEY, INTEGER;  
ID_Recipe:  INTEGER NOT NULL;  
Ingredient_Title: CHAR(64)
```

In my program, I have a recipe object that contains a vector of ingredients:

```
struct Ingredient
{
  int ID;
  int recipe_ID;
  std::string title;
};

struct Recipe
{
  int ID;
  std::string title;
  std::vector<Ingredient> recipe_ingredients;
};
```

In order to perform a *for each* iteration on a recipe in the table, I must load it from the database.  To complete the recipe, I have to load in all of the ingredients associated with the recipe.

The problem is that when I load in the ingredients, I lose the result set of the recipes.  The *MySQL Connector C++* can only handle one result set at a time.  I have had no luck in copying the results either (when the table size grows, I may not want to load in the entire results).

So, how can I maintain a cursor or pointer to the recipe table while I search and load from the ingredient table?

Here is what I want to do:

1. For each recipe in the table do:
2. Read recipe result row data into
   Recipe variable.
3. Use recipe ID to select all
   ingredients where Recipe.ID_Recipe =
   Ingredient.ID_Recipe.
4. Load results from ingredient table
   into vector of Recipe variable.
5. Pass recipe object to call-back
   function.
6. Advance to next recipe in the table.
7. End-for

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
(I'm using MySQL, MySQL Connector C++, Visual Studio 2008 - C++)

Comment: You don't actually need a join table for one-to-many relationships. But in your case it's a many-to-many relationship, because an ingredient can be used in multiple recipes, can't it?

Comment: This is the simplified presentation.  I have a table of all the ingredients.  There is one table that maps recipe IDs to Ingredient IDs, so that the primary key is compound, recipe ID + ingredient ID.  This allows for finding all the ingredients associated with a recipe without duplicating all the recipe attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, there's nothing in the MySQL Connector/C++ doc indicating that opening a second ResultSet invalidates the first one.  Please post the code you use to process the rows.  You may be doing something that closes the first ResultSet prematurely.

Comment: I wrote some simple test code that accesses the different tables using different ResultSets.  This code has no problems.  I then modified my recipe program and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just return one result set.  Have a column (or columns) called recipe which stays the same for each ingredient.  Do a join.

eg

`select * from recipe left join ingr on recipe. ID_Recipe = ingr. ID_Recipe`

This will give you a table you loop over... when the recipe name changes then you know you are on to a new recipe.

Comment: Although a good solution, this may be slow since each recipe name field also must be checked.

Comment: I don't think this is slow vs the overhead of doing multiple server queries (very very slow).  But I'm glad you found your bug.